# page getting stuck on CSS loading when user back

Tags: jquery, loading, preload

I wrote a simple jQuery code, With this aim :
when user click on a link in page, show loading before go to another page, So far everything is working fine.
the problem is this : when user go to page2 and then clicks on browser back button The page stays on loading and previous page not shown, I need a solution to solve this issue.
[Online Demo](https://limoo.in/test/)
jquery code :

```
! function (l) {
    "use strict";
    // preloader
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".lm-loading").animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, {
          duration: 500,
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.lm-preloader-number').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
              countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
            $({
              countNum: $this.text()
            }).animate({
              countNum: countTo
            }, {
              duration: 1000,
              easing: 'swing',
              step: function() {
                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
              },
            });
          });
          $(".lm-bar").animate({
            height: '100%'
          }, {
            duration: 1000,
            complete: function() {

              $(".lm-preloader").addClass('lm-hidden')
            }
          });
        }, 400);
    });
    // this is action after user click on a link
    $('a').on("click", function(){
        $(".lm-preloader").removeClass('lm-hidden');
        $(".lm-preloader-number").html("Loading <span class='one'>.</span><span class='two'>.</span><span class='three'>.</span>");
        $(".lm-percent span:nth-child(2n)").hide();
    });
}(jQuery);
```

sorry for poor English writing

Comment: I visited your demo page (FF102.0.1).. it loads to 100% and shows the content. Then I click on page2, and again it loads to 100% and shows the content. Then I go back and again it loads to 100% and shows the content. What's supposed to be wrong?

Comment: I looked at the website under Chromium and Firefox. Works fine in Chromium, on Firefox the loading bar jumps considerably in size, but it does load. What browser are you using?

Comment: go to home button works well because have a href attribute, but if you click browser back button or go back button (red button) page stuck on loading ...

Comment: Could be the problem is that your page is being cached. Have you tried triggering manual reload? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp